# sharepoint 2013 "open documents in client applications by default" is not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

I have to open any type of document(.doc, .pdf, .xls etc) in SharePoint web page itself. For that I have enabled a feature "open documents in client applications by default" for my web application.

when I tried to open a document but it  still not opening in browser (web page). I have tried every possible solution for it but still no luck.

My requirement is to show any document in SharePoint 2013 web page. Please let me now what I am missing now or any alternative way to do it?

I am working on SharePoint 2013.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware of [Office Web Apps aka Office Online](http://blogs.technet.com/b/officeasia/archive/2013/01/09/configure-sharepoint-server-to-open-office-documents-in-client-application-by-default.aspx)?

Comment: No idea of this. Let me explore myself on that.

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to distinguish two kinds of files: Office files and other files.

For Office files, you may open (and edit) them in the browser by using Office Web Application (OWA) if it's deployed and configured to work with SharePoint in your environment (or in SharePoint Online).
If OWA is configured correctly, supported Office documents (Word, Excel, ...) will open in HTML mode in the browser...
...Unless you activated the feature "open documents in client applications by default" that will force them to open in the client application, if present on the client machine (MS Word, Excel...).

For other file types (like PDF), the behavior is generally: will be downloaded by the browser to a local folder and be opened by the matching client application (Adobe Reader...)
Depending on the browser and/or the matching client application behavior/settings, the file may be open in the browser (thanks to the appropriate add-in installed by the target application).

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have activated "open documents in client applications by default", but document is not opening in browser. Any help.

Answer (score 0):

Evariste is Correct. I just want to add that If You are using SharePoint 2013 Online and not having any Content Types in Your libraries it will always (regardless of if You have chosen "Open documents in client applications by default") open in Office Web Apps when You "Create New". But when You open an existing document it should open in the client (if You have chosen "Open documents in client applications by default").

If You have Content Types in Your libraries and have chosen "Open documents in client applications by default" the will open in client also when You "Create New".

Comment: I am using "Sharepoint 2013"

Comment: @user2493287 online or onprem?