# Open new item direct with excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, excel

I am using O365 SharePoint and Create a WebPartContentType with an Excel-Template. So when you click on "New Item" it open the Template with Excel-Online.

Now my question:
Is it possible to open the Template with Excel-Office?

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Library Settings -> Advanced Settings

For 'Opening Documents in the Browser' choose 'Open in the client application'

Comment: Thank´s for the fast answer. I change the Type but it still open with Excel-Online. Now I wait for one Houre and try it again an hope it works than.

Comment: You have to have MS Office on your machine configured with office 365, check the answer to this question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150434/sharepoint-2013-open-documents-in-client-applications-by-default-is-not-workin

Comment: I Logoff SharePoint and go to my lunch break. After the lunch break I login an try it. The result: It works Thanks for your Help.